# Get the Email-Id of the Client PHP

Tags: php, gmail, google-oauth, google-api-php-client, google-api-client

I want So I've followed the instructions given on the following page
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app
However, it isn't too clear on how to get the currently signed in user's email id. The current scopes that I've set are for reading the person's profile, his email-id and gmail.readonly (reading all emails).
My question is, say I have the access token, and I've initialized the Google_Client object by setting the access token, how do I get the currently sign-in user's email?

Answer (score 0):

Heh, looks like I just needed to find the proper Google Service. Got this by going through the documentation.
https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/php/latest/class-Google_Service_Gmail.html
The code now is:

```
$gmail = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);
if($client->getAccessCode()) {
    $token_data = $client->verifyAccessToken();
    $email = $token_data['email'];
}
```

Also, for some reason, the line with $token_data doesn't seem to work, so I ended up using the REST API to verify the access token. Just replace that line with

```
$token_data = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token='.urlencode($client->getAccessToken()["access_token"])), true);
```